# how to set android's camera as the input of ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, server, camera, rtsp

I managed to run ffmpeg in Android Studio project, but don't know how to set the Android's camera as the input of ffmpeg.  Is it possible now?

If not, is there some open-sourced projects that can get Android's camera and turn the phone to a rtsp server? Then I can use ffmpeg to get that rtsp link.

Really appreciate it if some suggestions about this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ist Part of your question:
[Android Camera Capture using FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280722/android-camera-capture-using-ffmpeg)

2ndPart:

1.ffserver receives prerecorded files or FFM streams from some ffmpeg instance as input, then streams them over RTP/RTSP/HTTP. 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html

2.You can use GStreamer:
[Using Gstreamer or ffmpeg to create rtsp client on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328435/using-gstreamer-or-ffmpeg-to-create-rtsp-client-on-android?rq=1)

3.Not open source but Wowza mobile Sdk(RTMP),TokBox(based on WebRTC) etc can solve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already realised this. Also referred to the first link you provided. Used MediaCodec and AudioRecord to get raw H264 and AAC streams, then sent them to ffmpeg by a named pipe and an udp socket. It works fine.